# Meteor how to pass the data of an array in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, meteor

I am trying to make a form where you have a list with the names of your friends to invite them every name with a checkbox i already get the data and insert the data in a collection as an array but now i added a filter to the friends list and when i check the checkbox --> change the filter --> other name appears --> change the filter so the first name comes again but it isnt checked anymore so the data is lost

Thats the point why i created a event where the last names of this filter input is stored and when you change the filter and select some friends i want to combine the first and the second array to insert it in the collection.

This is it so far:

```
Template.NeuesEvent.events({
    "click .RadioButtonOnClick": function(event){ 
        var Zwischensumme = [];
             $.each($('.FreundeCheckbox:checked'), function(){            
                Zwischensumme.push($(this).val());
            }); 
        console.log(Zwischensumme);
        Session.set("Zwischensumme", Zwischensumme);   


    }
});
```

and here is the other event with the insert and the array I want all of the data go is "eingeladene":

```
Template.NeuesEvent.events({
    "submit .add-event": function(event){
        var Name = event.target.name.value;
        var Beschreibung = event.target.beschreibung.value;
        var Datum = event.target.Datum.value;
        var Autor = Meteor.userId();
        var Einladender = Meteor.user().username;
        var eingeladene = [-----Here the Data have to go-------- ];



        if (Name == "")
        {
            confirm("Das Event braucht einen Namen ;)")
        }
        else 
        {
        Meteor.call('addEvent', Name, Beschreibung, Datum, eingeladene, Autor, Einladender)

        event.target.name.value = "";
        event.target.beschreibung.value = "";
        FlowRouter.go('/meineEvents');

        return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what array you're trying to construct from your example above. You have one array in the `Zwischensumme` Session variable. Where's the other one. Also a security tip: *never* pass the current userId or any other information about the current user to a method as this enables spoofing. Always look up information about the current user in the method itself.

Comment: The array Zwischensumme gets updated and every time this happens the data should be stored in the array "var eingeladene" so the old data stays and some new fields from Zwischensumme are added and so on and on until the user submits and the array eingeladene gets inserted in the collection @MichelFloyd